# Wiki rendering in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, wiki

Client side rendering is useful when we want to use wiki like syntax. Unfortunately I have not found any library which gives wiki syntax rendering in GWT client side.

Does anyone knows such an API/library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also quite nice: http://code.google.com/p/gwtwiki/

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a Javascript wiki rendering API. There are a couple Mediawiki (Wikipedia syntax) ones listed at http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers.

There are also some Java-based wiki markup parsers; you could simply parse the wiki markup on the server side. Here are some examples:

- [JWPL](http://www.ukp.tu-darmstadt.de/software/jwpl/) contains a Mediawiki markup parser.
- [MathEclipse Java Wikipedia API](http://www.matheclipse.org/en/Java_Wikipedia_API)
- [Mylyn](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn/Incubator/WikiText)
- [java-wikipedia-parser](http://code.google.com/p/java-wikipedia-parser/)

Googling might turn up parsers for other wiki syntaxes, though Mediawiki seems to be pretty well-known.

Answer (score 1):

One of the XWiki developers writes in his blog, that they've developed a GWT based Wiki editor:

- [XWiki development in overdrive for 2009](http://massol.myxwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Blog/XWikiDevOverride)